# select temporary column with ascending values added

Tags: mysql, select, auto-increment, temporary

I am new to this forum and I am studying MYSQL.

I am creating a database of NBA players and I have added about 540 player records into table nba_players. When the records were inserted the nba_players.player_id column was set to auto_increment but it incremented starting from 531 and ended on 1000 something. Rather than truncate the whole table and reapply the INSERT statement I would like to try a different solution.

I am using workbench 8.0 so I am using a combination of query language and table manipulation through the workbench user interface.

So the alternative solution I am working on is to create a temporary column using the SELECT statement to bring up a temporary column with values 2 to 540. I would then copy the entire column and then use workbench to paste the rows using right click 'paste rows' into a new SELECT query:

```
SELECT player_id FROM nba_players
```

I have tried SELECT 2:540 as temp_column. Please dont laugh lol I am trying to get more fluent ;)

I suspect this could be done with the UPDATE command but like i said, I wanted to pursue this solution to add more tools for working with MYSQL to my arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

If your table (with 535 players)  have not value between 1 and 539  and is not retated to others tables using foreign keys you could try using var and update

```
  set @myid:=0;

  update 
    nba_players
    set player_id =@myid:=@myid+1
    order by player_id;
```

otherwise you could do the same in valid range (eg: @myid= 10000) for move the id out of range and then repeat the command strating form 0

Comment: well the update statement worked. First time I have used the set @myid:=0; statement, which i take to mean start at id 0. However could you please answer the part of the question that deals with using a SELECT statement to create a temporary column with values in ascending order to the N-th value? I have tried looking online for that answer and it appears that my question does not produce a result set that will give me an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the question on how to create a temporary table in MySQL that has one column with recursive value from 1 to 540 is to use the recursive CTE or recursive Common Table Expression. The specific query is as follows:

WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n)
as (
        select 1
        union all
        select n + 1
        from cte_count
        where n < 540
    )
select n
from cte_count;

Now maybe there is an update statement that could add the result into the player_id column. If I find that solution I will post it here.